# Negative lookbehind does not work with multiple alternatives in FileLocatorPro regex

Tags: regex, boost

```
(?<!ing|how|out)\sto\b
```

the expression I used in FileLocatorPro is ok, but after I　added some words in it, like

```
  (?<!ing|how|out|wants)\sto\b
```

it went wrong. Is there any limit of using "|"?

Comment: it says the expression is not valid for the expression type Regular Expression. Reported Error: Invalid lookbehind assertion encountered in the regular expression.@ Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: See the solution and explanation below. Please mark as accepted by ticking the grey tick on the left if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

The *Regular Expression* flavor used for the Perl compatible option is Boost, see [the *FileLocatorPro* docs](https://help.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/en/index.html?regular_expression_settings.htm):

> Perl compatible regexp syntax is based around the Boost regular expression engine and includes not only the functionality of the 'classic' regular expression engine but also additional Perl style expression enhancements detailed here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex.

Boost docs say that [*`(?<!pattern)` consumes zero characters, only if pattern could not be matched against the characters preceding the current position (pattern must be of fixed length).*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)

That means, all alternatives inside a lookbehind must be of the same length.

The work around is to chain the lookbehinds with alternatives of the same length:

```
(?<!ing|how|out)(?<!wants)\sto\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hNqMnK/2) (Python option is used because Python has the same lookbehind length restriction).